# getBooleanExtra() using only the default argument and not the one passed by putExtra()

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Here's the code. In this part, the `answerIsTrue` variable should be initialized to true, which it rightly does (I debugged and checked) and is rightly also passed into putExtra() (again, I debugged and checked).

```
mCheatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent i = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, CheatActivity.class);
            boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isTrueQuestion();
            i.putExtra(CheatActivity.EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, answerIsTrue);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

But coming to a different class, the variable `mAnswerIsTrue` gets assigned to false (probably due to the default argument) despite the argument being passed by putExtra() is true. Here's the code.

```
mAnswerIsTrue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, false);
```

I debugged this line as well, and it does get assigned to false. What could be wrong?

Here's the complete `CheatActivity` class:

```
public class CheatActivity extends Activity {
public static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE = "com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.answer_is_true";
private Button mShowAnswerButton;
private boolean mAnswerIsTrue;
private TextView mAnswerTextView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cheat);
    mAnswerIsTrue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(CheatActivity.EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, false);
    mAnswerTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answerTextView);
    mShowAnswerButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.showAnswerButton);
    mShowAnswerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            if (mAnswerIsTrue){
                mAnswerTextView.setText(R.id.true_button);
            }else{
                mAnswerTextView.setText(R.id.false_button);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Note: I'm a complete beginner, who just learnt debugging.

Comment: try sending hard coded true first your code looks ok

Comment: Just tried that. Still shows up as false. What and where's the problem? I hope you meant sending hard coded true using putExtra(). That's what I just tried, and the problem still persists.

Comment: Whats the values of `EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE`? May be it is matching with something else. Otherwise your code looks OK.

Comment: are you sure you are putting true into the intent

Comment: @M-WaJeEh here's what I declared EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE to be `public static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE = "com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.answer_is_true"; `

Comment: Just curious cause you have mentioned that you are beginner: You are calling `mAnswerIsTrue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, false);` in `onCreate()` of `CheatActivity`, Right?

Comment: No. Outside onCreate(). Why should it be inside onCreate()? Sorry, if it's a silly question. Shouldn't variables be outside onCreate(), usually, but maybe not in all cases.

Comment: Oh thats the reason. You have to initialize it inside `onCreate()`. Let me post an answer so other could benefit as well.

Comment: mAnswerIsTrue was actually always declared inside onCreate. Still doesn't work. I misunderstood your question interpreting you were asking about EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE being inside onCreate(), which isn't(obviously). Sorry about that. Anyways, it still doesn't work

Comment: plz post your code of `CheatActivity`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56331/discussion-between-m-wajeeh-and-slay).

Comment: I've posted the entire CheatActivity class as asked.

Comment: Issue is here `mAnswerTextView.setText(R.id.true_button);` I guess. `setText()` expects string id like`R.string.xxx`. Try setting some hard-coded string instead e.g. `setText("true")`

Comment: just log the value of the answerIsTrue in the button click.And check is it true?

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, CheatActivity.class);
         boolean answerIsTrue = true;
            i.putExtra(CheatActivity.EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, answerIsTrue);
            startActivity(i);

Comment: and tell me what u get in the next page

Answer (score 4):

I cannot be sure, but my best guess that, getBooleanExtra() is not good. I suggest using simple getExtras and then getting your value.

```
 i.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, value);

 Bundle args = MyActivity.getIntent().getExtras();
 boolean istrue= args.getBoolean(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, false);
```

Comment: No. Problem still persisting.

Answer (score 0):

In your `CheatActivity` initialize `mAnswerIsTrue` in `onCreate()` like this:

```
private boolean mAnswerIsTrue = false; // default value

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mAnswerIsTrue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, false);
}
```

Comment: mAnswerIsTrue was actually always declared inside onCreate. Still doesn't work. I misunderstood your question interpreting you were asking about EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE being inside onCreate(), which isn't(obviously). Sorry about that. Anyways, it still doesn't work. Anything else that could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

for getting the data use the code

```
Boolean answertrue =getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean(CheatActivity.EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE);
```

in button click use the code

```
Intent i = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, CheatActivity.class);
 boolean answerIsTrue = true; 
i.putExtra(CheatActivity.EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, answerIsTrue); 
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: try this and tell me what u got?

Comment: I've already debugged, and the value passed is true. Here's where it becomes false: `mAnswerIsTrue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(CheatActivity.EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, false);`. Check the code in he description for further context.

Answer (score 0):

" **Ctrl + B** " to get in method in API. (android studio)

```
public boolean getBooleanExtra(String name, boolean defaultValue) {

        return mExtras == null ? defaultValue :
            mExtras.getBoolean(name, defaultValue);

    }
```

**defaultValue** the value to be returned if no value of the desired
type is stored with the given name.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you rotate your screen, you should call pullExtra method. I am learning Android as well, but it seems to me that everytime onCreate method is called, Android app forgets all information about intend.

My code for that parts looks like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cheat);


        mAnswerIsTrue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, true );

        if(savedInstanceState != null ){

            mShownAnswer = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_IS_CHEATER, false);
            setAnswerShownResult(mShownAnswer);

            Log.i(TAG, String.format("IsACheater: %b", mShownAnswer) );
        }
        else{
            setAnswerShownResult(false);
        }
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Use instead of `.getBooleanExtra()` the `intent.extras.get()`.
So your code should be similar to this:

```
val mAnswerIsTrue = ((intent.extras.get("EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE")).toString()).toBoolean()
```

You need to cast, if you want to use the variable as an boolean.

If you want to put more extra, you need make a Bundle:

```
val extras = Bundle()
extras.putString("KEY_string", someString)
extras.putBoolean("KEY_boolean", someBoolean)

var intent = Intent(context,StartingActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtras(extras)
```