# Displaying buttonCheckAnswer in second activity

Tags: java, android

Using the code below I'd like this `buttonCheckAnswer` to get visible ONLY in other activity called `AnswerActivity.java`.

How can I set it?

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (position == (NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS - 1))
                checkSelected();
            else if (buttonCheckAnswer.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                buttonCheckAnswer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

**One more issue**,

how from this `getBooleanExtra` get two values R.string? So far I get only one value and the second one doesn't seem to exist.

```
textViewDisplayResult.setText(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("KEY_ANSWER", true)?getString(R.string.Good_answer):getString(R.string.Wrong_answer));
```

**FULL CODE**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static int NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS = 3;
    static boolean[] answer = new boolean[NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS];
    static boolean[] checked = new boolean[NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS];
    static boolean[] isAnswered = new boolean[NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS];


    private static Button buttonCheckAnswer;

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private List<Fragment> fragmentList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buttonCheckAnswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_check_answers);
    PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragmentList);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AnswerActivity.class);

        buttonCheckAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (checkAnswers())
                    intent.putExtra("KEY_ANSWER", R.string.Good_answer);

                else
                    intent.putExtra("KEY_ANSWER", R.string.Wrong_answer);

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });


        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if (position == (NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS - 1))
                    checkSelected();
                else if (buttonCheckAnswer.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                    buttonCheckAnswer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
    }

    public static void checkSelected() {
        for (boolean radioChecked : checked) {
            if (radioChecked) {
                buttonCheckAnswer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    private boolean checkAnswers() {
        for (boolean radioAnswer : answer) {
            if (!radioAnswer) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean allAnswersChecked() {
        for (boolean radioAnswer : isAnswered) {
            if (!radioAnswer) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And `AnswerActivity`

```
    public class AnswerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_answer);
        TextView textViewDisplayResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_display_result);

        textViewDisplayResult.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("KEY_ALL_CHECKED"));
        textViewDisplayResult.setText(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("KEY_ANSWER", false)?getString(R.string.Good_answer):getString(R.string.Wrong_answer));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put an `Intent` String extra from activities leading to your `AnswerActivity`.

```
String buttonVisibility = "false";
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnswerActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("visibility", buttonVisibility);
startActivity(intent);
```

and then on your AnswerActivity, you can read the value of the string extra by

```
String visibility = this.getIntent.getStringExtra("visibility");
```

You can use the visibility variable to change the visibility of the button. You can then set the default visibility to `View.VISIBLE` and only change it depending on the string extra the intent has.

**Note:**
**Be mindful that it is a `String` and not a `boolean`**

Comment: Thanks. I will try to implement it. Could you please help me with **one more issue**? I've updated my post.

Comment: One more question to you Joeb. How can I just change my above code to set this `buttonCheckAnswer` for `AnswerActivity`?

Comment: What string do you get?

Comment: I dont get your other question. What do you mean "set this `buttonCheckAnswer` for `AnswerActivity` "

Comment: For your `getBooleanExtra` question, please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24426797/getbooleanextra-using-only-the-default-argument-and-not-the-one-passed-by-pute) link.

Comment: As to `buttonCheckAnswer` I mean I'd like to have it displayed only in my `AnswerActivity`. Now I have it displayed only in my `Fragment3`. I guess this line `if (position == (NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS - 1))` sets it for `Fragment3` now. But I don't know how to change it for `AnswerActivity`

Comment: no, that line does not set it for `Fragment3`. What it most likely does is that it reads a `true` value in `position == (NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS - 1)` so that your `else` clause is no longer checked. Try removing your `else` before the second `if`.

it should look like this:

    if (position == (NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS - 1))
                checkSelected();
            else if (buttonCheckAnswer.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                buttonCheckAnswer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: So remove `else` but in your code there is `else` left..? And one more thing - what acutally means `position == (NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS - 1)`? Having this code the `checkButtonAnswer` appears in the `Fragment3` before the `Fragment` with the first `radioButtons`. And when I change from `-1` to `1` it appears in the `Fragment5` after the `Fragment` with the set of first `radioButtons`

Comment: kindly post your full code so that we can trace this problem