# Big Nerd Android GeoQuiz - answer not passed to CheatActivity

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm working on Big Nerd Android GeoQuiz Application, chapter 5.
The correct solution is not passed to CheatActivity.

This is cheat activity:

```
public class CheatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE = "org.mydomain.geoquiz.answer_is_true";

private boolean mAnswerIsTrue;
private TextView mAnswerTextView;
private Button mShowAnswerButton;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cheat);

    mAnswerIsTrue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE", false);

    mAnswerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer_text_view);

    mShowAnswerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_answer_button);
    mShowAnswerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mAnswerIsTrue) {
                mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.true_button);
            } else {
                mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.false_button);
            }
        }
    });


}

public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, boolean answerIsTrue) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext, CheatActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, answerIsTrue);
    return intent;
}
```

}

And it gets called by Quiz activity:

```
        mCheatButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cheat_button);
    mCheatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isAnswerTrue();
            Intent intent = CheatActivity.newIntent(QuizActivity.this, answerIsTrue);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Using the debugger I see that the correct value is passed. 
But in cheat activity when I set mAnswerIsTrue, it is always set as false.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: The exact same thing was solved in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24426797/getbooleanextra-using-only-the-default-argument-and-not-the-one-passed-by-pute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing two different strings in the intent: in the new Intent method you are passing the variable `EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE` which is define correctly in the beginning of cheat activity.
when you retrive the intent `mAnswerIsTrue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE", false);`
you are using the string "EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE" which is not the variable setted above. hence the mAnswerIsTrue variable bring the default value which is false.
so to sort out replace this

```
mAnswerIsTrue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE", false);
```

with this

```
mAnswerIsTrue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, false);
```

Comment: Yes. You're right. Thanks!